# Premium emoji in telegram bot on aiogram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

Is there a way to send premium emojis from a telegram bot using aiogram?

I tried searching in the documentation, but couldn’t find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send premium emojis because premium subscription for bots is still not available.

---

> Q: Can I buy a premium subscription for my bots?
> Premium bots are currently not supported. Telegram evolves quickly, be sure to follow our blog to find out if this feature becomes available in the future.

Source: https://telegram.org/faq_premium#q-can-i-buy-a-premium-subscription-for-my-bots

Answer (score 0):

If you buy username on [fragment](https://fragment.com) and set it to bot, bot will can send custom emoji. But for do it you should pay a one-time fee.

from https://fragment.com/about

> You can also upgrade collectible usernames to assign them to Telegram bots. To upgrade, assign the username to a bot and pay a one-time fee.